# Copy data from google datastore to CSV

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gsutil

I am storing data in google cloud datastore via an appengine project and would like to download one of the entities as a CSV file.

I have set up gsutil so that it defaults to this appengine project.
I have also created a bucket under cloud storage.

Is there a way to use gsutil to move data into the bucket?
gsutil cp  gs://bucket_name 
seems a likely candidate.

But IS this the way to go? And if so, what is the structure of the  URI?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lookup](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/lookup) method to retrieve and entity JSON presentation by key.

Comment: Thanks. Granted, I can convert JSON to CSV, but this seems a pretty round about way. Is there nothing more direct? (I already query the datastore using JDO, so I can write to file directly, so that is probably a more direct alternative.)